# How to use optaplanner to solve a nonlinear constrained multivariable equation - Java

Tags: java, math, optaplanner, equation-solving

I want to solve a nonlinear multivariable equation with discrete values like this one:

```
x*y + z + t - 10 = 0
```

with constraints:

```
10 < x < 100
```

etc..

I did some research and I believe optaplanner is the way to go. I downloaded the package from their website, but I am a little lost.

Can someone tell me how to write the code for this problem using optaplanner's libray?

Comment: What are `x`, `y`, `z` and `t`? OptaPlanner supports types, OO and polymorphism, so why regress to a non-OO model?

Comment: x,y,z and t are integer variables with constraints

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) to solve this. I'd recommend a good LU decomposition method.
Also there are more sophisticated libraries like: [FPL](http://www1.fpl.fs.fed.us/optimization.html) and [Benoit](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~benoit/Java/math/solvers/solvers.html)

There's no guarantee, of course, that there is a solution.

Comment: I think Jama is only for linear equations. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that's true, I updated the answer.